# PHP: Symfony2 MySQL SELECT query in controler

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, frameworks

I created a database on phpMyAdmin localhost. I have set database configurations in symfony and created doctrine mapper (entity). Now all I need is to make `SELECT` query and get information from database:

TABLE NAME: Profile
ROWS: 1

CONTROLLER CODE:

```
...
use Ignas\IgnasBundle\Entity\Profilis;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $profilis = new Profilis();

        return new Response('Id '.$profilis->getId());
    }
}
```

`getId` method is from `Entity/Profilis` file `Profilis` class.

Is there any easy way to do this? I searched for a while and all I could find was doctrine syntax that is not familliar to me at all.

Comment: Do you want to get all Profilis stored in DB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do it in different ways:

first of all, get the `EntityManager` in your `Controller`

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
```

in case it says it's deprecated you can also get it like:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
```

then you can do it with the `QueryBuilder` or with the `createQuery` method

With **Select** method (as suggested in the comments)

```
$profilis= $em->select('p.id')
              ->from('BundleName:EntityName', 'p')
              ->getQuery()
              ->getResult();
```

simple **Query**:

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT * FROM Profilis p");
$profilis = $query->getResult();
```

**NOTE**

both methods return an array of `Profilis` so you can simply loop them this way:

```
foreach($profilis as $p){
    // do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: createQueryBuilder is not found.

Comment: Oh nevermind, it seems that `createQueryBuilder` can't be called on top of the getRepository(). Instead of this I used: 
`createQueryBuilder('p')->select('p.*')->from('IgnasIgnasBundle:Profilis', 'p')`
And it worked.

Comment: Okay then I'll mark it as right answer :) And instead of select('p.*') write select('p.id'), my bad.